# React Native static navigationOptions not working when having drawer navigation inside stack navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using react native navigation v5 and I have a stack navigator that renders a drawer navigator, inside the drawer navigator I render all of my screens.
previously, it was the other way around- I had a drawer nav that renders the main stack nav, but the issue was that I wanted the drawer nav to be presented beneath the header bar, so after switch it works. The issue now is that I cannot change the component's header using `navigationOptions`

this is my stack navigator:

```
    <SafeAreaProvider>
     <Stack.Navigator
      openByDefault={true}
      backBehavior="history"
      initialRouteName={"Drawer"}
      screenOptions={screenOptions} 
      drawerPosition="right" 
      drawerType="front"
      >
    <Stack.Screen name="Drawer" component={DrawerNavigator} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</SafeAreaProvider>
```

also, these are my screenOptions:

```
    const screenOptions = useCallback(({navigation})=>{
    return {
        headerStyle: {
         backgroundColor: '#fff',
         height: 60,
         shadowColor: "#000",
         shadowOffset: {
           width: 0,
           height: 5,
         },
         shadowOpacity: 0.36,
         shadowRadius: 6.68,
         elevation: 11,
        },
        headerTitle: <RcText onPress={()=>navigation.navigate("Home")}>HELLO</RcText>,
        headerTintColor: '#404040',
        headerRight: ()=><Hamburger onPress={()=>navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())}/>,
        headerLeft: ()=><HeaderLeft navigation={navigation}/>,
        //headerTitle: <Header/>,
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontWeight: 'bold',
        },
    }
}, [])
```

and the drawer navigation:

```
    <Drawer.Navigator 
    drawerContent={(props)=><DrawerComponent {...props}/>}
    drawerPosition="right"
    drawerType="front"
    initialRouteName={"Otp"}
   // screenOptions={screenOptions}
    //overlayColor= "transparent"
    drawerStyle={{
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        width: '90%',
        //marginTop:100,
        //height: 450,
        shadowColor: "#000",
        shadowOffset: {
          width: 0,
          height: 5,
        },
        shadowOpacity: 0.36,
        shadowRadius: 6.68,

        elevation: 11,
    }}
>
    
    <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
    <Drawer.Screen name="WillBeAvailableSoon" component={WillBeAvailableSoonScreen} />
    <Drawer.Screen name="LetsStart" component={LetsStartScreen} />
    <Drawer.Screen name="HowMayWeHelp" component={HowMayWeHelpScreen} />
    <Drawer.Screen name="Interlude" component={InterludeScreen} />
    <Drawer.Screen name="Products" component={ProductsScreen} />
    <Drawer.Screen name="ProductFilterSequence" component={ProductFilterSequenceScreen} />
    <Drawer.Screen name="Otp" component={OtpScreen} />
    <Drawer.Screen name="Product" component={ProductScreen} options={{headerShown: false }}/>
    <Drawer.Screen name="ShoppingCart" component={ShoppingCartScreen} />
    <Drawer.Screen name="Video" component={VideoScreen} options={{headerShown: false }}/>
    <Drawer.Screen name="About" component={About} />
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

in my `Home` component I do

```
  static navigationOptions = ({navigation})=>({
       title: "My Home Screen"
  })
```

but it doesn't work, probably because the Drawer is rendering the screen and has no access to the header. so I need another way of organising the navigation so it will be possible to use `static navigationOptions` but also the drawer will be opened beneath the header.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out how to resolve this.
I moved the screens in which I want to change the nav options into the stack container and in react native navigation v5 it turns out the the old `static navigationOptions` in no longer working.
instead they added a `setOptions` method on the `navigation` object.
I am now using it with `useLayoutEffect` to change the navigation options.
It works for me only when the screen is located in the stack navigator.